# How to find the number of ways to form a queue given a restriction

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is my first time here.

Qns: How many different ways can four people A,B,C,D form a queue if

```
 a) B must stand infront of A, and C must stand in front of 
    D?
```

This is my method, which is correct

### bacd

### bcad

### bcda

### cbad

### cbda

### cdba

Total number of ways is 6.
Even though my answer is correct. I find that it is too tedious. If given a harder question, It will take a long time for me to solve it. Is there another faster way to solve this question?

-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $4!$ ways to arrange the queue without the order restriction.  Let us say that two queues are equivalent if one is obtained from the other by switching $a,b$ or $c,d$ (or both or neither).  Then each equivalence class has $4$ queues in it, so there are $6$ equivalence classes.  Noting that each class contains exactly one member that passes your tests finishes the claim.